# How to assign component's class method to (click) dynamically in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I am using angular 5. I know you can do something like this

```
<div (click)=foo()>click me</div>
```

for angular to call the `foo()` method in the component's class when the element is clicked. What if you want to pass methods to `(click)` dynamically, that is, you don't know what will be assigned to `(click)` when the view is being built like is happening below

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)=item.action>item.name</li>
</ul>
```

lets assume that the items array looks like this

```
let items = [
    {name: 'Smith', action: 'add'},
    {name: 'Paul', action: 'delete'}
]
```

I want a click on the `li` element containing Smith to call the `add()` method and a click on the one containing Paul to call the `delete()` method. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
let items = [
    {name: 'Smith', action: () => { console.log('add');} },
    {name: 'Paul', action: () => { console.log('delete');} }
]


<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="item.action()">items.name</li>
</ul>
```

even you can have argument in your functions for example

```
    {name: 'Smith', action: (somearg) => { console.log('add', somearg);} },

    <li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="item.action(argvalue)">items.name</li>
```